# Nunit3: how to save the test results while tests are running

Tags: nunit

NUnit3 Console runner saves test results in xml at the end of the test run. But in my case I want to save the partial results on each test failure, so that in case console runner crashes or is stopped, I can still get partial results for completed tests.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NUnit3's [TestContext](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext) that creates a [TextWriter](https://www.dotnetperls.com/textwriter) and save the output where ever you want.

I use Console.WriteLine() and read the Output in Visual Studio's Test Explorer (requires you have the NUnit3TestAdapter). This also works when I run tests via Bamboo. Anything written to the Console is saved in the Bamboo log.

Comment: my aim here is to convert the xml to an html report and use it in our in-house application to display result. But I don't want to wait for the test run to finish before I can access it, specially on test failures.

Comment: With the TextWriter, you can write out to a file (txt, xml, html, etc.) and parse it whenever/however you want.